# ln -s $SOURCE/* except - with find?

Tags: find, symlink

I want to do a symbolic link from all directories and files in the first node of `$SOURCE` to `$HOME/Destination/`. Pseudocode

```
ln -s $SOURCE/* exceptThese $HOME/Destination/
```

Proposal

```
find $HOME ! -name Data -o -name Labs -exec \
   ln -s "$0" $HOME/Documents/
```

where I am not sure about `$0`.

---

How can you symlink all except in the first node?

Comment: What do you mean by “first node”?

Comment: @Gilles I mean by the first node that `./` so not below. I do not know the precise vocabulary here.

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. Do you mean that you only want the files in `$HOME` and not under subdirectories, e.g. you want to process `~/foo` and `~/bar` but not `~/Data`, `~/Labs`, `~/foo/fee`, etc.?

Comment: @Gilles I want everything above the node i.e. subdirectories ...

Comment: *sigh* What. Do. You. Mean. By. “node”? It is not a standard English word with a comprehensible meaning in this context. **Explain** it, instead of always using “node” to define “node”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want to create symbolic links from `$HOME/this`, `$HOME/there/that`, `$HOME/Data/ddd`, etc. but not `$HOME/Data` or `$HOME/somewhere/Labs`, then the criteria for matching should be

```
find "$HOME" ! \( -name Data -o -name Labs \) -exec …
```

You were missing parentheses. Juxtaposition binds tighter than `-o` so `-name Data -o name Labs -exec …` executes the command for files named `Labs` only (except for files named `Data`, but none of them can also be named `Labs` anyway).

If you meant to exclude all the files under `Data` and `Labs`, then you need the `-prune` action, which tells `find` to skip the directories altogether, without traversing them recursively.

```
find "$HOME" \( -name Data -o -name Labs \) -prune -o -exec …
```

This excludes any subtree whose root is called `Data`, not just `$HOME/Data`. If you only want to exclude `$HOME/Data` but not e.g. `$HOME/sub/data`, you can use `-path` (if your `find` implementation supports it).

```
find "$HOME" \( -path "$HOME/Data" -o -path "$HOME/Labs" \) -prune -o -exec …
```

Now, for the `-exec` part. In a `-exec` action, use `{}` (in an argument on its own) to stand for the path that `find` found. Put a `;` (quoted so that it's passed to `find` and not parsed by the shell) at the end of the command to run.

```
find … -exec ln -s {} "$HOME/Documents/" \;
```

If you *only* want the files directly under `$HOME` and not the files in subdirectories, then `find` is not the best tool for the job: it's designed for recursive traversal. Use a shell loop instead. Note that the pattern `*` skips dot files, i.e. all files whose name begins with a `.`, and the pattern `.*` matches all dot files plus `.` and `..`, these two need to be skipped explicitly.

```
for x in ~/* ~/.*; do
  case "${x##*/}" in
    .|..|Data|Labs) continue;; # Skip those entries
  esac
  ln -s "$x" "$HOME/Documents";;
done
```

Comment: This is what I meant `find "$HOME" \( -name Data -o -name Labs \) -prune -o -exec …`.

Comment: @thomas_d_j Which one? I can't see a script that stops at the starting point here.

Comment: oops my bad, didn't see the `-o`; will delete comment...

Answer (score 1):

In Bash you can do it by enabling the extglob option:

```
$ shopt -s extglob                                #Enables extglob
$ ls -l "$HOME"/!(Data|Labs|Documents)            #Test run
$ ln -s "$HOME"/!(Data|Labs|Documents) \
        "$HOME"/Documents/                        #Create symlinks
$ shopt -s extglob                                #Disable extglob
```

Edit: using find as per your original post, this should work:

```
$ find "$HOME" \
    -mindepth 1 \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    ! -name Data ! -name Labs ! -name Documents\
    -exec ln -s {} "$HOME"/Documents/ \;
```

The `mindepth` option excludes the root dir.
The `maxdepth` option excludes subdirs.
Each `! -name` excludes one path.
The `{}` argument for `-exec` is what you were looking for instead of `$0`.

Answer (score -1):

To make the link for everything `find` finds other than its first result, you can do this:

```
for item in "$(find "$HOME" ! -name Data -o -name Labs | tail --lines=+2)"; do
    ln -s "$item" "$HOME"/Documents/
done
```

Comment: No, don't parse the output of find. `-exec` is the way to go.

Comment: Generally speaking, I agree.  However, the OP specifically called out to exclude the first result of `find`, which necessitates parsing it unless it's known by name, in which case an exclusion can indeed be sent to `find [...] -exec`.